# Let us change/select chat site from mobile chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, mobile-web

In the mobile chat, I can't find a way/option to change or select a chat site.

When I click on `site`, it **only** shows chat rooms for [Stack Exchange](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&nohide=true&host=chat.stackexchange.com).

> [image]

The option equivalent to `(more sites)` of desktop site is missing.

And hence unable change or select other sites. The only way is to manually change `host=` from address bar. Can this please be added to  the mobile site as well?

Comment: That's what "site" does... It shows all rooms on the site you are currently on. "All" shows all rooms **on that server**... But only MSE is on the server you're looking at. There's three servers. If you want to view chat rooms on Stack Overflow, you have to start on SO. Or if you want to view all rooms on the other sites, you have to start on any other site.

Comment: @Catija just clarified.

Comment: You can't do that on the desktop chat either can you?

Comment: @Cai You mean `(more sites)` option in dessktop view is useless?

Comment: Maybe I'm just being blind... Where is the "more sites" option? There is "all rooms", but that just lists all the rooms *on the current server*.

Comment: Yeah... I don't see "more sites" either... can you post an image of what you're talking about on the desktop view? Is it possible you have some sort of script or plugin?

Comment: @Cai https://i.imgur.com/j2Es92qh.jpg

Comment: That hovering box is not something I've ever seen.

Comment: Ah I found it! Ok, yes I see... that's not something I've ever used or seen but you're right it is missing from the mobile view

Comment: Well, mobile theme is minimal on purpose. This feature is quite "fancy", personally I don't think it should be added to mobile theme. If someone wants to  use such a feature, he/she can switch to full site theme, select site, and go back to mobile theme. No need for manual URL change.